# Docker Compose - how to include utility Python scripts?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a service that I originally had configured in my environment. I felt that the configuration was not very well documented and the service not easily deployable, so I decided to adopt Docker to solve that.

The service uses a Python script that has its own dependencies and can be called with a number of different arguments. Originally, the scripts dependencies were installed system-wide so I just hard-coded the path to the script in the service's code and it worked.

However, now that I'm trying to move to Docker I'm not sure how to deal with that. Some ideas:

1. bind-mount the script directory - but then how to make sure all its dependencies are available within the container environment?
2. dockerize the Python script and add it as a service to the docker compose YAML. Really unsure about this one as it's not really a service, just a utility script that exits as soon as it's done processing.

The Python script is also called with a combination of arguments. Not sure if it's relevant, but I noticed that when I create a new container from an image, I can't start the container again with different arguments - I have to re-create the container with different arguments. I really don't understand the idea behind this behaviour and would appreciate if somebody could explain the logic behind this.

Comment: So in your container you want the python service running and you should be able to pass all the arguments, that's your ask right?

Comment: If this is the canonical way to do this kind of thing, then I guess so.

Comment: Have you read through the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org) and similar documentation?  You should be able to declare all of your script's Python dependencies in a `setup.py`, `requirements.txt`, or `Pipfile`, and it can run in a virtual environment, without specifically needing Docker.

Comment: I agree. The question I have is: what is the best way to make this script available to my service that runs in a Docker container? Bundle the service and the script together and build the image then? Some other way?

Comment: Any solution? I ran into the same issue with node.js, but the principle is the same... So far I've chosen the 2. option, but it makes communication between the host and the container really complicated, since I have to forward IP addresses, and mount files via volumes.